# Android override objects for entire platform

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, android-source

Is there a way to override objects for the entire android platform without building your own custom version of android. For example the ArrayList object. Can I make it default to include an asterix (*) before every object in the array. Not only when it's called within my own app but for every app on that device. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to override objects for the entire android platform without building your own custom version of android.

No, for obvious security reasons.

> Can I make it default to include an asterix (*) before every object in the array

You cannot "include an asterisk" before an `Integer` or a `Socket`. Hence, you cannot "include an asterisk (*) before every object in the array" for arrays that are not arrays of `CharSequence` or other things that allow this sort of string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. About the integers and sockets. What I mean is. When information is displayed in a listview, lets say for example a listview has shows a string as an item in a list. For every string in a listview to have a * before it? Is that possible? If its not within my own app

Comment: The reason I question this. How do launchers work. They seem to take over the entire app and customize it.

Comment: @shoriwa-shaun-benjamin: "Is that possible?" -- no. "How do launchers work" -- I do not know what you consider a "launcher" to be. Usually, that term is used for a feature of a home screen, and a home screen does not "take over the entire app and customize it".

Comment: Alright I assumed since the home screen could be customized by creating your own launcher. Then other features could be customized as well. Also considering there are apps that change the font and etc throughout your app.